# Sony Vaio Laptop slow app starts, freezing, getting error at boot

Tags: laptop, 19.10, vaio, sony

Applications slowly start, and the mouse sometimes freezes for a long time. With the troubleshooting below we have realised there may be a kernel issue and more.

- OS: Ubuntu 19.10 64-bit
- RAM: 3.7Gib
- CPU: Intel Core i5-2450 @ 2.50GHz x 4
- GPU: Intel Sandybridge Mobile/AMD Turks
- DE: 3.34.2 GNOME
- HDD: 640.1GB

I want it to be as fast as it was when using windows, it also ran games smoother. Sorry for the ambiguity but I am at a beginner level when trying to diagnose PC's and only ask hereafter scouring the internet for a while.

I have tried to install 18.10 via flash drive but the laptop doesn't want to read it, I'm sure the flash works as I can move files to and from the thing. Tried all ports and the obvious boot priority in bios for external 1st. Unsure how to deal with this.

Also here are some messages I receive when booting up, unsure what they mean but they weren't there a while ago:

```
   [   0.819892] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
   [   0.941895] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
   [   0.941831] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
   [   0.945499] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
   [   0.949091] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
   libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe. with 'drm_kms_helper'
   /dev/sda2: clean, 367863/39043072 files, 19322276/156151552 blocks
   [   22.174940] kvm: disabled by bios
   [   22.196457] kvm: disabled by bios
   [   22.214414] kvm: disabled by bios
   [   22.234472] kvm: disabled by bios
```

Here is free -h:

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.7Gi       2.2Gi       336Mi       436Mi       1.2Gi       900Mi
Swap:         2.0Gi        58Mi       1.9Gi
```

df

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1933720        0   1933720   0% /dev
tmpfs             392192     1656    390536   1% /run
/dev/sda2      613753264 66387636 516118936  12% /
tmpfs            1960956   318892   1642064  17% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1960956        0   1960956   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1          1024     1024         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop0        164096   164096         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop3         49536    49536         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1474
/dev/loop4         15104    15104         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/399
/dev/loop2         56320    56320         0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop5        160512   160512         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
/dev/loop6          4352     4352         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop9        207744   207744         0 100% /snap/vlc/1049
/dev/loop7         46080    46080         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
/dev/loop10         1024     1024         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/93
/dev/loop11        15104    15104         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/495
/dev/loop8        177664   177664         0 100% /snap/skype/115
/dev/loop14         3840     3840         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/135
/dev/loop15         4480     4480         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/704
/dev/loop12        93568    93568         0 100% /snap/core/8592
/dev/loop18         3840     3840         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/127
/dev/loop13        93568    93568         0 100% /snap/core/8689
/dev/loop17        56064    56064         0 100% /snap/core18/1668
/dev/loop19       207872   207872         0 100% /snap/vlc/1397
/dev/loop16       179072   179072         0 100% /snap/skype/118
/dev/sda1         523248     7932    515316   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs             392188       76    392112   1% /run/user/1000
```

Screenshots of SMART DATA;
[image: screenshot 1/2]

[image: screenshot 2/2]

Also:

```
grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

sysctl vm.swappiness :

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

ls -al /boot

```
total 183756
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Mar 30 20:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root     4096 Oct 18 17:41 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   235803 Jan 31 18:32 config-5.3.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   235824 Feb 28 05:35 config-5.3.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   236702 Nov 25 02:01 config-5.4.0-050400-lowlatency
drwx------  3 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Mar 28 19:01 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Mar 20 18:03 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.3.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 47883549 Feb 19 21:18 initrd.img-5.3.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 47886202 Mar 20 18:04 initrd.img-5.3.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 42610261 Mar 30 20:59 initrd.img-5.4.0-050400-lowlatency
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Mar 20 18:03 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.3.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  4702736 Jan 31 18:32 System.map-5.3.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4704561 Feb 28 05:35 System.map-5.3.0-42-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4695408 Nov 25 02:01 System.map-5.4.0-050400-lowlatency
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Mar 20 18:03 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.3.0-42-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 11391736 Jan 31 19:27 vmlinuz-5.3.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 11399928 Feb 28 05:40 vmlinuz-5.3.0-42-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 11582336 Nov 25 02:01 vmlinuz-5.4.0-050400-lowlatency
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Mar 20 18:03 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.3.0-40-generic
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116399/discussion-on-question-by-morsbuntu-sony-vaio-laptop-slow-app-starts-freezing).

Answer (score 2):

You probably have multiple problems.

**Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed**

<strike>`sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)` failed to resolve this problem, so we're going to change the compression method for the effected `/boot/initrd.img-*` file.</strike>

In the `terminal`...

`cd /etc/initramfs-tools` # change directory

`sudo cp initramfs.conf initramfs.bak` # backup this file before editing

`sudo -H gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` # edit this file

Locate this:

```
#
# COMPRESS: [ gzip | bzip2 | lz4 | lzma | lzop | xz ]
#

COMPRESS=lz4
```

Change it to this:

```
#
# COMPRESS: [ gzip | bzip2 | lz4 | lzma | lzop | xz ]
#

COMPRESS=gzip
```

Save the file and quit `gedit`.

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)` # recreate /boot/initrd.img-*

`reboot` # reboot the computer and verify no error messages

**RAM & Swap**

The `free -h` command shows us that you don't have enough RAM or swap. This is also proven because of "*Applications slowly start, and the mouse sometimes freezes for a long time*".

Memory should be configured in matched pairs to take advantage of memory interleaving. With 4G RAM, you could have one 4G DIMM, or two 2G DIMMs. If you have one 4G RAM DIMM, you could add another 4G RAM DIMM. If you have two 2G RAM DIMMs, you should replace both with a matched pair of 4G or 8G DIMMs. `sudo lshw -C memory` can be used to see your current configuration.

In the mean time, we need to increase your /swapfile size from 2G to at least 4G.

**Warning: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Best to use copy/paste.**

In `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #1:**

Haven't been able to locate a BIOS change/update for Sony SVE14AA11M (or SVE14A1V1EP). Can't find at Sony web site...

**Update #2:**

Discovered system has the wrong kernel for 19.10. It has 5.4.0-050400-lowlatency. It should be running 5.3.0-42-generic. We'll have to work on getting the correct kernel booting...

**Update #3:**

All of a sudden GRUB menu doesn't want to work. Am diagnosing now...

**Update #4:**

Reinstalling Ubuntu...

Comment: Could not boot new OS from flash (tried a few USB drives) and there is no optical drive. Is there a way to do it via network?

Comment: @Morsbuntu How did you create your USB flash drives? What software did you use? Did you checksum the downloaded .iso file to make sure that you got a good copy?

Comment: After all, I ended up just booting to a new version of Windows 10 only. Thanks for your help.